# Recovering Synalogy NAS Data using Ubuntu

Tags: mount, hard-drive, raid, mdadm

I have a Synalogy DS1515+ with 5 Drives and we have been told by Syanlogy to use Ubuntu to access the Drives externally. The drives use Raid 5 but for some reason we are unable to mount them when we use the below

```
Install mdadm by typing “sudo apt-get install mdadm”. Once given the option, select “No Configuration” and the installation will be complete.
Install lvm2 using the command “sudo apt-get install lvm2”
```

After installing the required software, you can mount all of the Synology Diskstation hard drives using “mdadm -Asf && vgchange -ay”

we do not get the response that we see on the instructions. it does not show that the drives are mounted

Comment: What response do you expect from the instructions, and what do you actually get?

Comment: Please exactly state your commands and their output. I once went through a similar set of commands. I had to `ssh` into the NAS itself, then do `mdadm` with various options, `lvmdiskscan`, `lvscan`, `vgchange -ay` and finally `mount`. After much experimentation, I could access my files.

Comment: I start with sudo apt-get install mdadm and the reply is that it loads up a file and is updated.the next command sudo apt-get install lvm2 it again updates but when i enter the 3rd command (mdadm -Asf && vgchange -ay)  I have issue. it firstly states that i a mnot a super user, i have then entered  sudo -i which takes me to root from ubuntu:ubuntu. when i then add the same command Asf it does nothing i will get a cursor return. no response of any kind other than , that if i pressed return on its own. Hope that makes sense. if you need more i can get images